# UnitTests in React - Method “text” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, react-redux

App.js:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
       <MyComponent />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

MyComponent.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class MyComponent extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
         isShown : false
    }
}

  clickHandler = () => {
      this.setState(({isShown}) => ({ isShown : !isShown  }));
    }


    render() {
        const {isShown} = this.state
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick= {this.clickHandler}>Click Me</button>
                {isShown && <div>Text goes here</div> }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default MyComponent
```

MyComponent.test.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import Enzyme, {shallow} from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

Enzyme.configure({adapter : new Adapter() });

describe('MyComponent', () => {
    it('should show text', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
        const text = wrapper.find('div div');
        expect(text.text()).toBe('Text goes here');
    });
});
```

I have installed the following command 
 `npm install --save-dev enzyme enzyme-adapter-react-16`

I don't know why the below error coming:
MyComponent › should show text

```
Method “text” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.

  11 |         const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
  12 |         const text = wrapper.find('div div');
> 13 |         expect(text.text()).toBe('Text goes here');
     |                     ^
  14 |     });
  15 | });

  at ShallowWrapper.single (node_modules/enzyme/src/ShallowWrapper.js:1652:13)
  at ShallowWrapper.text (node_modules/enzyme/src/ShallowWrapper.js:1093:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/MyComponent.test.js:13:21)
```

The same code executed once upon a time with the same configuration..but now it's not executing? 
Could someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 2):

in the MyComponent property isShown is set false by default, so when you try to find second div it's undefined. At first, you must click button after that you can check text.

```
wrapper.find('a').simulate('click');
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.Your answer solved my proble

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to find a div in a div inside your component, which only has one div element. When enzyme talks about nodes its talking about elements, so basically is telling you that the find function isn't finding any element that matches the parameter you passed as an argument. I think the problem is that, by default, the second div element is hidden. You should try setting the state prop isShown to true before trying to find the element.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.Your answer solved my proble

Answer (score 0):

there is no 2 division in your jsx component 
on shallow rendering you state is false and your second div did not render

```
 this.state = {
     isShown : false
}
```

and your test can not show

```
{isShown && <div>Text goes here</div> }
```

fix it by make your default state to true , like that

```
 this.state = {
 isShown : **true**
}
```

or another way change your test code into

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
    it('should show text', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
        wrapper.setState({ isShown : true });
        const text = wrapper.find('div div');
        expect(text.text()).toBe('Text goes here');
    });
});
```